# Google Script (code.gs) -- scan large range in Google Sheets; use as dropdown menu in HTML page

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I found this Google script/html trick that lets you enter a word, and then it'll scan a Google Sheet for any duplicate values.
https://script.gs/autocomplete-drop-down-options-from-spreadsheet-data/

The code ONLY works with one column though. I have a huge range of data (cells B2:AP40) that I want to use... and I've tried changing the range accordingly, but it doesn't work at all.

Below are the original test codes I used on my own site, which I took from the website above.

PS: I'd really like for the code to merge multiple ranges together in a dropdown (ex: column B, column I, column P). Is that possible?

**My Code (code.gs)**

```
var ID = '1ZlTo7wQPEGKG4ZNEd4PPPr2vxQxPUKHSdd5UuHoFvZ0';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle('Index');
}

function getOptions() {
  var rangeValues = activeSheet.getRange(2,2,activeSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    return rangeValues;
}
```

Comment: I asked you the permission to view your project. The access is denied.

Comment: Can you make the code public or create a new one with dummy data in order to check it? Also, how have you tried to change the range, what is it that is not working?

Comment: @MikeSteelson: I tried giving you access and it's saying I can't. The gs file is "malformed" somehow.....sigh.

Comment: @Kessy: the original GS code (which is the first URL I posted) does work. Maybe you can use/copy that one? Also, I did change the range in the RangeValues line.  I changed the first two numbers to "2,8" (and that partially worked...but it only showed Column H's text).

Comment: Have you tried to share the script file? The macros part of the script link is created when deploying, please share the script file and not the deployment. Also have you considered iterating over the three columns and storing the values inside an array?

Comment: I'll remove the script.google.com link for now, as it seems to require authentication. The alternative is the closure of the whole question, which is generally not desirable.